# MySQL duplicate 'ID' = 0 and cant put AUTO_INCREMENT on

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm busy with transferring an old website to new hosting.
Now it's almost done, but there is something wrong with the database some primary keys don't go AUTO_INCREMENT. So now I have a lot of duplicated IDs that are all 0.

Is there a way in SQL that I can update all id's where = 0 to plus those?
The last ID which is filled good is "2108" so the next id needs to be "2109" and after that ++ them.

```
SELECT * FROM `x9i8Z_yoast_seo_links` WHERE `id` = 0
```

Please help me out

Comment: But how do you know the sequence of the rows where `id = 0`. Always **remember** that data is stored in an unordered fashion. As of now, all the rows with `id = 0` are peers. Do you want to give them any random numbering ? Or, do you have some other column, such as a `date_created` field, on the basis of which we can identify their sequence.

Comment: There is nothing like date_created or something like. So i was thinking to update random numbering..

Comment: Are you using latest version of MySQL (8.0.2 and above) ?

Comment: I use: 5.5.60-MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre MySQL 8.0.2 solution would be using [User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). Since ordering is not important in your case, we can determine a sequential row number value directly (without worrying about the order). It will be starting from the "last good id" value + 1. We will then update the `id` value for the rows, where `id` value is 0.

```
UPDATE `x9i8Z_yoast_seo_links` AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 2108) AS user_init -- 2108 is your "last good id" 
SET t.id = (@rn := @rn + 1)
WHERE t.id = 0
```

---

**Demo - Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table test
(id int);

insert into test 
values (1),(2),(3),(4),(0),(0),(0),(0);
```

---

**Query #1: Data before update operation**

```
select * from test;

| id  |
| --- |
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
| 4   |
| 0   |
| 0   |
| 0   |
| 0   |
```

---

**Query #2: Update operation is done**

```
update test AS t
cross join (select @rn := 4) AS user_init 
set t.id = (@rn := @rn + 1)
where t.id = 0;
```

---

**Query #3: Data after the update operation is done**

```
select * from test;

| id  |
| --- |
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 8   |
```

---

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/74BU2a7hHZarBkkzxQ93fM/0)